# Unable to create scheduled query with multiple SQL statements on BigQuery via sdk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sdk

I have 2 SQL statements which are `DELETE` and `INSERT`. The `INSERT` must be run after the `DELETE`. I'm planning to create a scheduled query with `DELETE ...; INSERT ...;` statement via sdk `bg mk`

However, I'm able to create scheduled query successfully with ONLY 1 statement (`DELETE` or `INSERT`) from sdk by

```
bq mk \
    --transfer_config \
    --project_id='my-proj-id' \
    --schedule='every day 00:01' \
    --target_dataset='my_dataset' \
    --display_name='query_name' \
    --params='{"query": "DELETE ..."}' \
    --data_source=scheduled_query
```

When I tried

```
bq mk \
    --transfer_config \
    --project_id='my-proj-id' \
    --schedule='every day 00:01' \
    --target_dataset='my_dataset' \
    --display_name='query_name' \
    --params='{"query": "DELETE ...; INSERT ...;"}' \
    --data_source=scheduled_query
```

The schedule query is successfully created, but it's failed to run, and I got error

```
Error code 9 : Dataset specified in the query ('') is not consistent with Destination dataset 'my_dataset'.
```

**Note**:

- I'm able to create the schedule query with multiple SQL statement via Cloud console (UI).

---

**Update**

Full command

```
bq mk \
    --transfer_config \
    --project_id='my-proj-id' \
    --schedule='every day 00:01' \
    --target_dataset="my_dataset" \
    --display_name='del-insert-test' \
    --params='{"query": "DELETE FROM my-proj-id.my_dataset.my_table WHERE DATE(timestamp) = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY); INSERT INTO my-proj-id.my_dataset.my_table SELECT res.col_a, res.col_b, res.col_c, timestamp FROM my-proj-id.my_dataset.my_raw_table, UNNEST (result) as res WHERE DATE(timestamp) = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY);"}' \
    --data_source=scheduled_query
```

Note that the SQL statement is not the actual one, but it's similar one, and I'm able to run the SQL statement on cloud console successfully

Comment: Can you try to use an array? `--params='{"query": ["DELETE ...; ","INSERT ...;"]}'`

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere it doesn't work ;( 

`BigQuery error in mk operation: Parameter type required for query: STRING, Parameter type provided in transfer config: list_value. Config name:`

Thanks

Comment: I posted a dummy anwser (better formatting than comment). It works for me. Can you share more about your commands?

Comment: Can you share to us your Google SDK toolkit versions?

Comment: @Nick_Kh

Google Cloud SDK 334.0.0
alpha 2021.03.26
bq 2.0.66
core 2021.03.26
gsutil 4.60

Comment: Can you revise an update especially `--params=` flag, is it correct composition without `query` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

It worked like a charm for me

```
  bq mk \
        --transfer_config \
        --project_id='gdglyon-cloudrun' \
        --schedule='every day 00:01' \
        --target_dataset='dlp_test' \
        --display_name='query_name' \
        --params='{"query": "DELETE from `gdglyon-cloudrun.dlp_test.name` where id=11;INSERT INTO `gdglyon-cloudrun.dlp_test.name` VALUES (11,111,\"@me.com\");"}' \
        --data_source=scheduled_query
```

Can you share more about your requests?

Comment: I updated the full command to the original question. The command is not actual one, but similar one. Thanks!

Comment: Is it normal that you forget the `{"query":}` in your params value? (in your question update). Is it a typo or your real issue?